# Python calculate area of circle from two given points A and B

Tags: python, area, calculation

new to Python and programming in general. First homework and a little stumped on this question.

Given  two  points  A(x1,  y1)  and  B(x2,  y2)  in  the  plane.
Write  a  program  to  calculate  the  area  of  a  circle centered as A and go through B.
Hint: The radius of the circle will be the distance between A and B.
AB2 = ((x1 – x2)2 + (y1 – y2)2).
R = AB2 ** 0.5.

I am using PyCharm community edition and python latest version

Comment: You have a hint to calculate the radius of the circle. You probably know the formula for the area of a circle (pi * r * r). Try writing that out in code.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a basic math problem not realy a code problem but anyway:

```
PI=3.14

pointa={"x1":1,"y1":1}
pointb={"x2":2,"y2":2}
r=((pointa['x1']-pointb['x2'])**2 +(pointa['y1']-pointb['y2'])**2)**0.5
area=PI*(r**2)

print(area)
```

replace the x1,x2,y1,y2 values as you wish in the pointa and pointb dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Python includes direct support for complex numbers, which makes the radius calculation much easier.

```
import math

A = complex(1, 1)  # x1, y1
B = complex(2, 3)  # x2, y2

radius = abs(A - B)
area = math.pi*radius**2
```

Comment: In the calculation of the area, I believe you have an extra 2.

Comment: for b, why (2, 3) and not (2, 2)?

Comment: @p7ul They could be any numbers - they correspond with the second point (x2, y2). The first pair could be any other number as well.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon I see, first week of python and first time encountering complex() method. So the benefit of using complex() in this instance is due to the 'imaginary' parts provided in the question, allowing the calculation of r to be simplified? Am I following you?

Comment: @p7ul Yeah, you can kind of think of `complex` as being a built-in system for handling 2D points.